# Integrate $e^{-(x^2-b^2)^2}$ over the real line

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to integrate $e^{-(x^2-b^2)^2}$, with $x$ takes value in the whole real line. I tried polar coordinates but cannot figure it out. Can anyone provide some hints here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot indefinitely integrate this function, there is no known or standard function (closed form) $f(x)$ such that : $f(x) = \int e^{-(x^2 - b^2)^2}dx$.

You can only evaluate a definite integral probably, or the Taylor expansion (series). Keep in mind that generally, $e^{-x^2}$ cannot be integrated indefinitely. You can evaluate through calculus methods though, some specific definite integrals. Take a look at the following :

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+(e%5E(-(x%5E2+-+b%5E2)%5E2)

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5E(-x%5E2)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

You can search more up just by googling the expression or writing it's formal name which is : Gaussian Integral .

Comment: This question is not about the indefinite integral but rather the definite integral over the real line.

Comment: @KoA 3 It never said "definite" and over the real line means that : $x \in \mathbb R$. So before downvoting, read the question more carefully, because it is not my mistake if it isn't describing what the questioner wants. Also, I linked gaussian integral links below (which are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ .So whatever he wanted to ask, I answered for everything.

Comment: I took "where x takes values in the whole real line" to mean $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x^2-b^2)^2} \,dx$. Regardless, this isn't the Gaussian integral. (For example in the case b = 0, the integral is equal to $2\Gamma(\frac{5}{4})$).

Comment: Gaussian integral gives information on how to calculate it. Also, you took it, it wasn't written clearly, yet you downvoting for no reason.

Comment: The articles I provided also have solution for the **EXACT** same problem he has. So, before downvoting and making non-constructive comments please read the full answer and the content within it. Also, integrals of this form, are called generalized Gaussian Integrals.

Comment: I apologise, I did not see the section at the bottom of the article - if you could add an edit to your answer I could reverse my downvote.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answers. But is my question related to generalized Gaussian Integrals? I wanted to figure out how to use generalized Gaussian to integrate mine.

Comment: Yours have a general $b$ in it which is of the form $\int e^{a(x^2 -b^2)^2} dx$ with $a=1$

Comment: Thanks, any ideas for integrating the form you mentioned?